# WindowsIdentity client username and domain return wrong value C#

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, windows-identity

i'm trying to get the username and domain from Windows, using

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
windowsIdentity.Name;
```

but its always returning 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. What could I do to return the correct value?

Thanks

Comment: What is the result, when you use `User.Identity.Name` instead?

Comment: Always 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Comment: Sounds like you're calling this from within ASP.  Which will return the identity of the apppool it is running under and not the name of the logged on user.

Comment: And how could I do it properly?

Comment: "do it properly" depends on what you expect the correct value to be.

Comment: I expect the windows user name and the computer domain.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18452903/2132796

Comment: Herdo with these 3 steps in this link I got the right domain/name, but I need a 'hybrid' system that could log in with Form and Windows authentication.
I wish I could get this values using Form Auth.