# C# Active Directory Client User name

Tags: c#, authentication, web

I have website in mvc c#, running on a server.
I want to bypass the login page and authenticate a user if the user is present in active directory.
For my website, i have forms authentication and anonymous authentication enabled.

The problem is, i want to find out the name of user who is visiting the website. The user can be present on internet. With this name, i will do a lookup in Active directory and do the validation.

I am unable to find the user name. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452878/get-domain-user-id-in-asp-net?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal This always shows the name of the app pool running the site. Whereas I am looking to find out the user name or computer name of the person hitting the website. Be it on internet or intranet.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Active Directory Authentication` in mvc by using Active Directory as the `Membership Provider` and get the username as

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
if (user != null)
    string name = user.UserName;
```

Comment: It throws a SQL exception