# Get a user's Windows logon id in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dns, userid

I'm writing an ASP.NET v4.5.2 Windows Application / Windows Form for our sales team to use and I don't want them to have to log in.  I want to compare their windows domain/userid to a userid that I have in a database for authentication.  I can get the domain/userid to display correctly in Visual Studio by using:

```
string userLogin = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

But when I deploy the application to our server this is what is displayed:

```
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR
```

The server is 2012 running IIS 8 and here are the settings for this web page:

```
Anonymous Authentication: Enabled
ASP.NET Impersonation:    Disabled
Basic Authentication:     Enabled
Digest Authentication:    Disabled
Forms Authentication:     Disabled
Windows Authentication:   Enabled
```

I've read this: 
    [Get Domain User ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452878/get-domain-user-id-in-asp-net)
 and followed the instructions but run across problems.

The first problem is that when I Disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS I get a 404 - File or directory not found error.

Another problem is that when I put this tag in web.config

```
<authorization>
 <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I also get the 404 error.

I have also changed authentication mode in web.config to this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

And still get the 404 or incorrect domain/user information (depending on the IIS settings).

I've started a project named test just to debug this problem.

When I disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS the url changes to this:
    servername/test/Account/Login?/ReturnUrl=%2Ftest%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Ftest%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Ftest%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252Ftest%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252Ftest%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252Ftest%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252Ftest%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252Ftest%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252Ftest%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252Ftest%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252Ftest%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252Ftest%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252Ftest%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252Ftest%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252Ftest%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252Ftest%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252Ftest%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252Ftest%25252525252525252525252525252525252F

Keep in mind that I'm writing my own login and not using .NET's.

My apologies if this is a duplicate question but I've done a lot of reading on here and other blogs and still get the same behavior no matter what I try.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I hope you got solution here. please refer this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184685/how-do-i-get-the-currently-loggedin-windows-account-from-an-asp-net-page).

Comment: @Sudhakar when I use System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Tostring() I get a HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found error.  The url is too long.  I then changed the httpRuntime in web.config to: maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="65536" enable="true" and still get the 404.15 error.

Comment: Disable anonymous and basic.

Comment: @mason:  I have set Anonymous Authentication and Basic Authentication both to disabled and get 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Then have you made you're requesting the right directory? What URL are you requesting? What directory if the root of your site? What does your site's file structure look like?

Comment: I have a directory called test as the root that I created just to troubleshoot this problem.  It is in wwwroot and it will display the site if Anonymous Authentication is set to Enabled only.  As soon as I disable it, I can't display the site. I think it has to do with the length of the url when I disable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: Then show that error in your question. Sounds like a redirect loop.

Comment: "The first problem is that when I Disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS I get a 404 - File or directory not found error." was in my question.